# how to display image in yii using CHtml::image()?

Tags: yii

i have stored pdf.png in C:\wamp\www\pipelinespark\images\pdf.png

i have used `$imghtml=CHtml::image('pdf.png');`
then i getting error like.

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   pipelinespark/administrator/index.php/spark/pdf.png".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me!

```
<?php
 echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/path_to/images /'."$model->logo","$model->Name",array('width'=>100,'height'=>100));?>
```

Comment: Consider removeing " from calls to model's attrs (it is unnecessary here and it is slow): `echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/path_to/images /'.$model->logo,$model->Name,array('width'=>100,'height'=>100));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/" . $data->image); ?>
```

Where `$data` is the returned value form actionIndex

Answer (score 0):

All of them works for me

```
<?=CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/path-to-images/logo.png", "LOGO")?>
<?=CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/path-to-images/logo.png")?>
<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->basePath."/../images/profile-image/".$data->avatar); ?>
```